# How to add data to a bunch of sorted files

Tags: algorithm, sorting, external-sorting

I apologize if this has been repeated before, but I couldn't find any posts with the wording I chose. I'm preparing for interviews, and I've been reading up on external sorting. For instance, if you want to sort several hard disks of 32 bit integers, you could make a counting sort and use 64 bit counters to count the 32 bit integers. Then, at every possible 32 bit integer value, you would have a counter representing it. You can also use external merge sort for similar things, taking O(nlogn) time instead of O(1) time. However, I've been thinking about a case that is probably very common, but I can't think of the best way to do it - adding new data to a bunch of sorted files possibly across many hard disks.

If there data were in memory, one could use a heap (priority queue) to accomplish this insert in logn time. However, we can't make a heap from hard disk space. With lists, you would have to use an O(logn) search to find the data's place (for binary search, sorted), then bump the rest of the data backward or forward, or you may not have to shift anything depending on the implementation of the container(arrays, linked lists, etc.). In the hard disk world, though, reads and writes are much more expensive than in RAM, so inserting data somewhere then shifting (rewriting) the rest of the data seems prohibitively expensive. Are there any techniques for this that any of you could recommend to me? I'd be happy to read myself, I just couldn't find the right way to word my question to find any information. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say read up that file of your sorted data, read up the file that you want to be sorted and added to there, buckle up the counters and plain overwrite the sorted data file with newly calculated one. Straight reading is largely less expensive on modern disk systems than random reading, and you will anyway need a position for every int you find, thus a single sequential read of the entire volume will be less time-consuming than ~32 reads of a single sector per number of the file to be sorted.

Also, I'd say sorting 32-bit ints is best done with result already in form of counters, especially at extra-large scale like "several hard disks", you will expect to have at least 1 in almost every bucket in 32-bit space, so storing 64 bits *2^32 could be smaller than say 2^33 32-bit zeroes then 2^32 ones then...

Comment: Excellent point! You seem very knowledgeable so i'll ask a followup if you don't mind. Say we have some string data, where we don't have a maximum length. For instance, an entry could be "Hello" or "fsdhgsdgghfgjdftjfhsg", it doesn't matter the length. One entry is one entry. Here, we can't use counters because creating a unique counter for each string would take (26 chars)^length counters, where length is not limited. To get the files sorted in the first place, we can use external merge sort, where the merge compares strings based on alphabetical order.

Comment: Yes, if you can't bucket sort, external merge sort is the way to go with such data sizes. Also, an external merge sort is a one-pass on a pre-sorted input data, but it'll be better to actually not change the file that's the accumulator, but instead write a new file, then delete the old one and rename the new one into an old one. This limits the sorting operations to one at a time, but usually when you sort something, you need an exclusive lock so you can freely manipulate the data.

Comment: Now here is my actual question: Given I have several files of sorted strings, how may I add an additional string most efficiently? In other words, I have a ton of sorted strings across many files/disks. I have a string, "sdgsghdsagdf" that I wish to add to storeage. Must I do another external merge (which would take near O(n) time, since the vast majority is already sorted), or should I find where the string should go (can use sort of a binary search, since data is sorted for O(logn) time.) and insert it, then rewrite all subsequent data? Or is there another way? Thank you!

Comment: Ohhh!!!! So I could read in the file that should have something inserted, delete that file, create a new file with the new insertion, and rename it to the old one? This would limit us to changing just a small fraction of the data. If this is what you were saying, that is?

Comment: Hmm. If you need to add a single string, then binary insertion will be better. If you need to add a whole file of strings, then external merge sort will be better performance-wise. But, if you are planning to do a bunch of 1-string insertion operations, I'd say you should make a temporary file that will get sorted normally, then do a single external merge.

Comment: Hmm so would it be feasible to say "Store all incoming insertions into a temporary file. When a size threshold has been reached, perform an external merge on all data and create a new temporary file to capture new insertions". Basically, we have this buffer or queue that's capturing new insertions, and when it reaches a threshold, we merge (but new insertions can still enter the queue in the meantime). That is, when the queue reaches threshold, it empties. Then it can keep filling again while the emptied data gets merged

Comment: Yes, I think so. But you have to worry about crash recovery with such an approach, should you be asked for it.

Comment: Well thank you very much, that was very helpful! Now I think I know how to answer such a question - which are quite common in this field (computer science / software engineering)! To recap on one last thing about the binary insertion since I don't think you responded to my little revelation up there: To do a binary insert, I simply find the file where I would be inserting the new string, read that file into memory in parts, then write each part to a new file, inserting the new string where it needs to go, then writing the rest of the file. Then, delete old file, replace with this new file.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately in order to maintain a *SOLID* file of sorted strings, you need to overwrite your file during each insertion. But this can be either postponed or circumvented if you will have a "sorted file" with a certain internal structure, that will allow both small insertions and fast external merge sorting. It'll take some more time to design and implement this, as well as more space to store and update such a file, but the majority of overwritings will be eliminated.

Comment: You have helped me a great deal with your responses, I wish I could give you more "upvotes". Thank you for spending the time to help me understand everything - at this point I feel pretty confident, and I plan on doing some test coding of the various things we discussed. Certainly not on multi-drive, but multi-file (say 10 GB a peice) is perfectly reasonable, since that's more than the RAM I have. I marked this as answered and hopefully this will help someone else in the future. Thanks again, have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

If you look up 'external sorting' here (or elsewhere) you will find discussions of what you are describing.  external-sorting is a tag here as well.

> In the hard disk world, though, reads and writes are much more
>   expensive than in RAM, so inserting data somewhere then shifting
>   (rewriting) the rest of the data seems prohibitively expensive.

External sorting is for cases where you do *not* have sufficient memory (or enough 'per process' in most cases) to do it internally.  It's not uncommon to have data sets too large to hold in memory at once.  So you accept the higher runtime cost of I/O bound sorting.

Comment: Certainly, I'm just seeking the best way to insert new data into already sorted data on a disk, given the fact that I/O is slow. I'll do some more searches on external sorting though, thank you for the reply

Answer (score 1):

If you have space in memory to hold the file, and you have a set of numbers whose smallest element is k, you are going to have to re-write all the numbers in the file that are larger than k.  There is no way around this.  They are all going to have to shift at least one position.

If you are looking to exploit the fact that most of the array is already sorted, and you have the space in memory to do so, then sorting the inserted elements and merging it with the list of elements that are larger than its smallest member is a good, fast way to do this.  EG:

DISK:

1 2 3 4 5 6 8 10 11 12

Insertions: 9 7 13

Sort the insertions:

7 9 13

Find the subset of the sorted list on disk that applies:
8 10 11 12

Merge the elements in (as in Mergesort:)

7 8 9 10 11 12 13

Copy them back to disk:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

If, on the other hand, your space in memory is prohibitively smaller than the total size of the list, other techniques might be advisable.  For example:

1 2 3 4 .. 1000 1002 1003... 999,998, 1,000,000...

as your list on disk and

1001, 999,999

as your insertions.  In this situation, you will want to go through each element, calculate the number of elements in the insertion list which are smaller than that element, and then do so.  In this simple example the naive counter is very fast - you can see for 1,000,0000 that two jumps are needed.  If the number of insertions might be comparatively large, you can sort your insertions and then use binary search on this element to find where each element in your larger array might lie.  This will give you information about how many items you can copy over.  So, the corresponding values of jump for the top would be:

0 0 0 0 ... 0 1 1 ... 1 2

Hopefully you can see a fairly obvious method by which you might want to decide to write one of your insertion elements to disk.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply!